# Regex to exclude word

Tags: regex

I have following expression:

2016-02-25 time=10:14:22

Here i want date and time in single group i.e 2016-02-25 10:14:22 and I dont want time= in my output.

Output should be 2016-02-25 10:14:22.

Please help me write regex which could exclude "time=" portion from the string.

Thanks,
atul

Comment: Yes this is PCRE. I need to extract this timestamp property from the raw log for SIEM.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a regex for this. You can do a replace using your prefered language.

Java Example:

```
String expressionString = "2016-02-25 time=10:14:22";
String convertedString = new String(expressionString).replace("time=", "");
```

If you want to do it with regex anyway, do like this:

```
/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}) time=([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})/g
```

Substitution:

```
$1 $2
```

[RegexPal Example](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=94266)

Comment: Thanks Andre...but with this regular exp. I am having 2 capture group but I want output in single capture group without "time=" string in output.